# Lock screen after period of inactivity, but not on closing the lid

Tags: laptop, power-management, lock-screen, lid

Running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, I want that

- when I leave my laptop untouched for 5 minutes, turn the screen off
- 1 minute after turning the screen off for inactivity, lock the screen.
- when I close the laptop lid, do NOT immediately lock the screen, but act like if the lid was still open and lock after 5+1 minutes (or similar).

In *System Settings → Brightness & Lock*, if set *Lock* to <kbd>ON</kbd> and configure the appropriate time (1 minute), it locks the screen accordingly after it has been turned off for inactivity. However, it also immeidately locks the screen on closing the lid, which I don't want.
Setting it to <kbd>OFF</kbd> makes it not lock the screen on closing the lid, but also leaves it unlocked after turning the screen off for inactivity.

I have set both "lid-close-actions" to "nothing" in dconf already:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
'nothing'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action
'nothing'
```

How can I make Ubuntu lock the screen only after a specific time of user inactivity, regardless of the lid position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background script below will do pretty much exactly as you describe

- switch off the screen after x seconds
- lock the screen after y seconds

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# set screen off after x seconds
off = 300
# lock screen after x seconds
lock = 360

# check idle every x seconds
res = 3

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def test(t, threshold):
    return int(t)/1000 < threshold

testoff1 = True
testlock1 = True

t1 = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(res)
    t2 = get("xprintidle")
    testoff2 = test(t2, off); testlock2 = test(t2, lock)
    if (testoff2, testoff1) == (False, True):
        subprocess.Popen(["xset", "dpms", "force", "off"])
    if (testlock2, testlock1) == (False, True):
        subprocess.Popen(["gnome-screensaver-command", "-l"])                
    testoff1 = testoff2; testlock1 = testlock2
```

#### How to use

Like you mention, you need to switch off existing lid actions:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
```

and:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
```

and furtermore:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

since we now take care of our own procedures.

***then:***

1. The script uses `xprintidle`, to check the idle time

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xprintidle
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_times.py`
3. In the head section of the script, set the idle time to switch off the screen (in seconds):

   ```
   # set screen off after x seconds
   off = 300
   ```

   and the time to lock the screen:

   ```
   # lock screen after x seconds
   lock = 360
   ```

   These times are set independently to each other, you may set both in any order you like (either lock first, then switch off, or the other way around)

   You *can* set the time "resolution", the frequency the idle time is checked, (and thus the set time is rounded by):

   ```
   # check idle every x seconds
   res = 3
   ```

   but you might as well
4. Test- run it:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_times.py
   ```
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_times.py
   ```

#### Explanation on the concept

- The command `xprintidle` returns the current idle time (no input from mouse or keyboard)
- The script then tests if the *set time* is smaller then a *defined threshold*, and compares the state with a few seconds ago.
- If there is a change in state (True --> False) any action can be taken. This is done for both switch off screen, running:

  ```
  xset dpms force off
  ```

  and lock screen, running:

  ```
  gnome-screensaver-command -l
  ```

#### Notes

- Off course we can also make the time(s) to switch off and lock the screen *arguments* to run the script with:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  import subprocess
  import time
  import sys

  off = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 300
  lock = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else off + 60
  # check idle every x seconds
  res = int(sys.argv[3]) if len(sys.argv) > 3 else 5

  def get(cmd):
      return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

  def test(t, threshold):
      return int(t)/1000 < threshold

  testoff1 = True
  testlock1 = True

  t1 = 0

  while True:
      time.sleep(res)
      t2 = get("xprintidle")
      testoff2 = test(t2, off); testlock2 = test(t2, lock)
      if (testoff2, testoff1) == (False, True):
          subprocess.Popen(["xset", "dpms", "force", "off"])
      if (testlock2, testlock1) == (False, True):
          subprocess.Popen(["gnome-screensaver-command", "-l"])
      testoff1 = testoff2; testlock1 = testlock2
  ```

  Then running:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/set_times.py 300 360
  ```

  will switch off the screen after five minutes, lock the screen after six.
- The additional burden of the script is zero.

Comment: Thanks. I made some edits to your code and fixed a few bugs... ;-) Also, you should probably add that in *System Settings → Brightness & Lock*, I have to switch the *Turn screen off when inactive for* to *Never* and *Lock* to *OFF*.

Comment: @ByteCommander I copied the `gsettings` commands from  your question, so I copied your bugs :) Ah, I also copied sys.argv[1], forgot to change it...